# Boton se expande con el ScrollView

Tags: java, android

Me gustaría ponerle un menú a mi aplicación el cual se pueda deslizar los botones horizontalmente y cuando coincide la barra del scroll con el botón, este botón se expande/agranda.

Estaba pensando en utilizar un HorizontalScrollView para colocar los botones y la animación mas o menos me guió como hacerla, pero estoy teniendo problemas para hacer la parte lógica debido a que nose por donde empezar (soy un principiante xD)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, tambien podrias hacerlo con un recyclerview :D . Y como lo estas haciendo actualmente?

Comment: quizás podrías usar ViewPager y simular que son botones XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo ..

lo encontré en

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823713/how-to-scale-up-recycler-view-center-item-while-scrolling-in-android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgVQp.png)

```
public class CenterZoomLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

    private final float mShrinkAmount = 0.15f;
    private final float mShrinkDistance = 0.9f;

    public CenterZoomLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CenterZoomLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public int scrollVerticallyBy(int dy, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int orientation = getOrientation();
        if (orientation == VERTICAL) {
            int scrolled = super.scrollVerticallyBy(dy, recycler, state);
            float midpoint = getHeight() / 2.f;
            float d0 = 0.f;
            float d1 = mShrinkDistance * midpoint;
            float s0 = 1.f;
            float s1 = 1.f - mShrinkAmount;
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                float childMidpoint =
                        (getDecoratedBottom(child) + getDecoratedTop(child)) / 2.f;
                float d = Math.min(d1, Math.abs(midpoint - childMidpoint));
                float scale = s0 + (s1 - s0) * (d - d0) / (d1 - d0);
                child.setScaleX(scale);
                child.setScaleY(scale);
            }
            return scrolled;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int scrollHorizontallyBy(int dx, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int orientation = getOrientation();
        if (orientation == HORIZONTAL) {
            int scrolled = super.scrollHorizontallyBy(dx, recycler, state);

            float midpoint = getWidth() / 2.f;
            float d0 = 0.f;
            float d1 = mShrinkDistance * midpoint;
            float s0 = 1.f;
            float s1 = 1.f - mShrinkAmount;
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                float childMidpoint =
                        (getDecoratedRight(child) + getDecoratedLeft(child)) / 2.f;
                float d = Math.min(d1, Math.abs(midpoint - childMidpoint));
                float scale = s0 + (s1 - s0) * (d - d0) / (d1 - d0);
                child.setScaleX(scale);
                child.setScaleY(scale);
            }
            return scrolled;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

el resultado es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas Gracias!